# Problema con migración de usuarios

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema con una actualización masiva de usuarios con Django. La idea es buscar todos los usuarios y pasar a minúscula todos los correos electrónicos.

Esta es la migración:

```
def update_email_to_lower(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model('userprofile', 'User')
    conflicts = 0

    for user_update in User.objects.all():
        email = user_update.email
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).count() == 1:
            user_update.email = email.lower()
            user_update.save()
        else:
            conflicts += 1
    print conflicts
```

Cuando se corre la migración genera el siguiente error:
[image: log_error]

En donde `get_full_name` es un método de mi modelo `User`:

```
def get_full_name(self):
    """Returns the full name for a user
    """
    if self.first_name and self.last_name:
        return u'{0} {1}'.format(
            self.first_name.strip(),
            self.last_name.strip()
        ).title()

    elif self.first_name:
        return u'{0}'.format(self.first_name.strip()).title()

    elif self.last_name:
        return u'{0}'.format(self.last_name.strip()).title()

    else:
        return self.email.split('@')[0].lower()
```

tengo un metodo save personalizado:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.id and not self.avatar:
        self = set_user_initials_avatar(self)
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

estos son los métodos que se llaman en el método save:

```
def set_user_initials_avatar(user):
    """Set the initials avatar for a user instance.
    """
    if user.first_name and user.first_name.strip():
        if user.last_name and user.last_name.strip():
            initials = (
                slugify(user.first_name.strip())[0]
                + slugify(user.last_name.strip())[0]
            )
        else:
            initials = slugify(user.first_name.strip())[:2]
    else:
        initials = user.email.split('@')[0][:2]

    user.avatar.save(
        u'{0}.png'.format(int(time.time())),
        generate_initials_image(user.color, initials.upper()),
        save=False,
    )

    return user

def generate_initials_image(color, initials):
    """Generate an image with the initials given.
    """
    url = 'http://dummyimage.com/400x400/{0}/ffffff.png&text=+{1}+'.format(
        color,
        initials,
    )
    return ContentFile(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

Buscando encontre que debía agregar: `use_in_migrations = True` ([Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#using-managers-in-migrations)) en mi `UserManager`:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_active=True):
      # ...
```

Pero aún continua el error.

¿Alguien tiene idea de qué es lo que sucede?

Comment: Hola Felipe, bienvenido a SOes, ¿qué versión de Django estás usando?, ¿estás usando un modelo `User` personalizado?

Comment: Hola César, estoy usando la version 1.8.8 y estoy usando un modelo personalizado.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el archivo de migración completo? No veo por ningún lado la razón por la cual se está llamando a la función `get_full_name`, en todo caso pon el error completo también. Yo acabo de hacer una prueba y me funciona perfecto, parece que el problema está por otro lado y eso que yo estoy con Django 1.8.2

Comment: @César edite la entrada para que revises el error. gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: La acabo de ver, ¿le has hecho una sobreescritura al método `save` de tu modelo?

Comment: @César actualice la entrada con información del método save.

Comment: Sigue siendo un misterio para mi saber desde dónde se llama a la función `get_full_name`

Comment: Y para mi, cuando corro el método en shell plus funciona!, cuando utilizo una consulta para cambiarlo `User.objecs.filter(id=user.id).update(email=user.email.lower())` funciona pero es muy poco eficiente, son 500000 registros. Gracias @César

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionar este tema corriendo el script desde la consola.